# Ubuntu 14.04 - resolution stuck on 640x480 running in virtual box 4.3.10 ver on windows 7

Tags: virtualbox, 14.04, resolution

I am using virtual box 4.3.10 updated version and it caused my Ubuntu 14.04 to be stuck on small resolution. Can anyone help me to fix this issue? I was read on the internet you can resolve this by installing the " insert guest additional image". When I do this it gives me an error message saying you cannot mount it this image or force it to mount .
If I select force nothing really happens. I have downloaded the "guest image" to the vbox in guest account. but it doesn't let me install it cause I am not the su . I am new at Linux. Please advise what steps to take. Thanks

I fixed it 2 min ago see link below

[How do I install Guest Additions in a VirtualBox VM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-a-virtualbox-vm)

Comment: see if this helps you: http://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-a-virtualbox-vm/

Comment: Yes its fixed I just saw that 2 min ago. Thanks

Comment: Great! Hope all else runs well :)